# Dart/Flutter: Custom Action Error The getter 'shared' isn't defined for the type

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am breaking my head over this error. I am humbly reaching out for some help.

I keep receiving the error below. However, in the examples listed on the GitHub repo (here: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/blob/main/example/lib/main.dart), the .shared getter properties are shown. I am using the OneSignal Fluuter package (onesignal_flutter: ^5.0.1) https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter

```
The getter 'shared' isn't defined for the type 'OneSignal'. Try importing the library that defines 'shared', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'shared'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the action in which I am trying to implement:

InitOneSignal

```
import 'package:onesignal_flutter/onesignal_flutter.dart';

Future<void> initOneSignal() async {
  // Set the log level for debugging (optional)
  OneSignal.shared.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose);

  // Initialize OneSignal with your App ID
  await OneSignal.shared.init(
    "API_KEY", // Replace with your OneSignal App ID
    iOSSettings: {
      OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt:
          false, // Set to true if you want the default iOS prompt
      OSiOSSettings.inAppLaunchUrl: true,
    },
  );

  // Request permission from the user for notifications
  final status = await OneSignal.shared.getPermissionSubscriptionState();
  if (status.permissionStatus.status != OSNotificationPermission.authorized) {
    // Handle the case where notification permission is not authorized.
    // You can show a dialog or perform any other desired action here.
    // For example, you can request permission again or inform the user about the need for notifications.
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the 5.0.0 release ([see](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/blob/user_model/main/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md#initialization)). It seems like the example on GitHub was created before that release.

Please take a look at the [OneSignal example](https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter/example) on pub.dev it uses a version above 5.0.0.

There you can see that the `setLogLevel` method should be: `OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose)` and the `init` method should be `OneSignal.initialize`